# Change opacity of other images/linkbutton except the one selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 3 images which i included in a linkButton and 3 different tables which i've set the visibility to 'False'. Once i've clicked on the 1st image/linkButton, the other 2 images/link button's opacity will be change to a lighter one, and also my 1st table visiblity will be set to true.
the same goes for the other 2 images/linkbutton.

so far what i've found are mostly for *a href* and not *linkButton*.i'm very new to jQuery and i would really appreciate if anyone could help me here.

this is what i've found, i wanted the same except it is for linkButton:
http://jsfiddle.net/gCsRL/1/

when i try with the following code, i have no problem:

```
<a class="images"  href="#"><img class="click" src="Images/Level2.jpg" height="133"/><br/><br/></a>
```

but because i want a linkButton, i tried to add the *asp:linkButton* in, but is throwing me an error saying **"Control 'lbl1' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbl1" runat="server"><a class="images"  href="#"><img class="click" src="Images/Level1.jpg" height="133" /><br/><br/></a></asp:LinkButton>
```

my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.images').click(function() {
    // Make all images (except this) transparent
    $('a.images').not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.4 }, 300);
    // Make this opaque
    $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);
});

});
```

i don't understand!!! can any kind soul out there help me please!!

-----EDIT-----

Ok it turns out i really didn't put the runat in form.
i tried using a href instead now but when i added an id to it, the animation is not working.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="fades_test.aspx.vb" Inherits="fades_test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.images').click(function() {
            // Make all images (except this) transparent
            $('a.images').not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.4 }, 300);
            // Make this opaque
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="images" >
    <a class="images" href="#" runat="server" >
        <img class="click" src="Images/Level1.jpg" height="133" /><br />
        <br />
    </a>
    <a class="images" href="#" runat="server" id="img2">
        <img class="click" src="Images/Level2.jpg" height="133" /><br />
        <br />
    </a>
    <a class="images" href="#" runat="server" id="img3">
        <img class="click" src="Images/Level3.jpg" height="133" /><br />
        <br />
    </a></div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="tblLevel1" runat="server" visible="false" style="z-index: 100; left: 50px;
                position: relative; top: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <br />
                        <font color="gray" style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Level 1 Quality Policy & Quality Manual</b></font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ...
            </table>
            <table id="tblLevel2" runat="server" visible="false" width="650px" style="z-index: 100;
                left: 50px; position: relative; top: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <br />
                        <font color="gray" style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Level 2 QMS Procedures</b></font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
               ...
            </table>
            <table id="tblLevel3" runat="server" visible="false" width="650px" style="z-index: 100;
                left: 50px; position: relative; top: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <br />
                        <font color="gray" style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Level 3 QMS Forms</b></font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ...
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

the code behind:

```
 Protected Sub img1_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles img1.ServerClick
    tblLevel1.Visible = True
    tblLevel2.Visible = False
    tblLevel3.Visible = False
End Sub

Protected Sub img2_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles img2.ServerClick
    tblLevel1.Visible = False
    tblLevel2.Visible = True
    tblLevel3.Visible = False
End Sub

Protected Sub img3_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles img3.ServerClick
    tblLevel1.Visible = False
    tblLevel2.Visible = False
    tblLevel3.Visible = True
End Sub
```

here inside my div id="images", the 1st image that is without an id, is working properly, meaning it fades out the other 2 images but it is not showing me tblLevel1!!.
for the 2nd n 3rd image that has an id, is not fading the other images but it is showing me the respective tables.

**----------------EDIT-------------------------**

i'm using Masterpage.master in this

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" CodeFile="timg.aspx.vb" Inherits="timg" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"%>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<br />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.images').click(function() {
            $('a.images').not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.4 }, 300);
            // Make this opaque
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);

            //hide all tables   
            $('[id*=tblLevel]').hide();
            //show indexed tabled
            $('#tblLevel' + ($(this).index() + 1)).show();
        });
    });
</script>

        <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,40,0"
                width="1000" height="238" id="myMovieName">
                <param name="movie" value="SWF/ban_hse.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="autohigh" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="black" />
                <param name="”menu”" value="”false”" />
                <param name="FlashVars" value="”init=yes&check=true”" />
                <embed src="SWF/ban_hse.swf" width="1000px" height="238px" name="myMovieName" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
                </embed>
            </object>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <br />
            <font color="CornflowerBlue" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: CG Omega;"><b>Quality
                Management System</b></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table width="100%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td width="3%"></td>
        <td width="17%">
            <div style="height: 35px">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lblQMS" runat="server" Text="Quality Management System" ForeColor="gray"
                    Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="false" Font-Names="CG Omega" Font-Size="16px"></asp:LinkButton></div>
            <div style="height: 35px">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lblMBEA" runat="server" Text="Monthly BE Articles" ForeColor="gray"
                    Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="false" Font-Names="CG Omega" Font-Size="16px"></asp:LinkButton></div>
        </td>
        <td>
<table width="100%">
    <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">
            <br />
            <strong>SOC- ISO 9001:2008 Certificate &nbsp;&nbsp;(16th Sep 2009 to 31st Aug 2012)</strong><br />
            Click <a href="HSE/QBE/Swiber_ISO 9001.2008 Certificate.pdf" target="_blank"><font
                color="blue"><u>here</u></font></a>&nbsp; to download
            <br />
            <br />
            <strong>ISO 9001-2008(E) QMS Requirements</strong><br />
            Click <a href="HSE/QBE/ISO 9001-2008(E) QMS Requirements.pdf" target="_blank"><font
                color="blue"><u>here</u></font></a>&nbsp; to download
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div id="div1">
                <a class="images" href="#">
                    <img class="click" src="Images/Level1.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </a><a class="images" href="#">
                    <img class="click" src="Images/Level2.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </a><a class="images" href="#">
                    <img class="click" src="Images/Level3.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id="tblLevel1" runat="server" style="z-index: 100; left: 50px; position: relative;
                            top: 0px; display: none;">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <br />
                                    <font color="gray" style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Level 1 Quality Policy & Quality Manual</b></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>

                        <table id="tblLevel2" runat="server" width="650px" style="z-index: 100; left: 50px;
                            position: relative; top: 0px; display: none;">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <br />
                                    <font color="gray" style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Level 2 QMS Procedures</b></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                             </table>                         
                        <table id="tblLevel3" runat="server" width="650px" style="z-index: 100; left: 50px;
                            position: relative; top: 0px; display: none;">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <br />
                                    <font color="gray" style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Level 3 QMS Forms</b></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**----------Source Code------------**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.images').click(function() {
            $('a.images').not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.4 }, 300);
            // Make this opaque
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);

            //hide all tables   
            $('[id*=tblLevel]').hide();
            //show indexed tabled
            $('#tblLevel' + ($(this).index() + 1)).show();
        });
    });
</script>

    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,40,0"
                width="1000" height="238" id="myMovieName">
                <param name="movie" value="SWF/ban_hse.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="autohigh" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="black" />
                <param name="”menu”" value="”false”" />
                <param name="FlashVars" value="”init=yes&check=true”" />
                <embed src="SWF/ban_hse.swf" width="1000px" height="238px" name="myMovieName" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
                </embed>
            </object>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <br />
            <font color="CornflowerBlue" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: CG Omega;"><b>Quality
                Management System</b></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table width="100%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td width="3%"></td>
        <td width="17%">
            <div style="height: 35px">
                <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblQMS" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lblQMS','')" style="color:Gray;font-family:CG Omega;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;">Quality Management System</a></div>
            <div style="height: 35px">
                <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMBEA" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lblMBEA','')" style="color:Gray;font-family:CG Omega;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;">Monthly BE Articles</a></div>
        </td>
        <td>
<table width="100%">
    <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2">
            <br />
            <strong>SOC- ISO 9001:2008 Certificate &nbsp;&nbsp;(16th Sep 2009 to 31st Aug 2012)</strong><br />
            Click <a href="HSE/QBE/Swiber_ISO 9001.2008 Certificate.pdf" target="_blank"><font
                color="blue"><u>here</u></font></a>&nbsp; to download
            <br />
            <br />
            <strong>ISO 9001-2008(E) QMS Requirements</strong><br />
            Click <a href="HSE/QBE/ISO 9001-2008(E) QMS Requirements.pdf" target="_blank"><font
                color="blue"><u>here</u></font></a>&nbsp; to download
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div id="div1">
                <a class="images" href="#">
                    <img class="click" src="Images/Level1.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </a><a class="images" href="#">
                    <img class="click" src="Images/Level2.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </a><a class="images" href="#">
                    <img class="click" src="Images/Level3.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tblLevel1" style="z-index: 100; left: 50px; position: relative;
                            top: 0px; display: none;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
                                    <br />
                                    <font color="gray" style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Level 1 Quality Policy & Quality Manual</b></font>
                                </td>
</tr>
</table>
   <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tblLevel2" width="650px" style="z-index: 100; left: 50px;
                            position: relative; top: 0px; display: none;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
                                    <br />
                                    <font color="gray" style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Level 2 QMS Procedures</b></font>
                                </td>
</tr>
</table>

                        <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tblLevel3" width="650px" style="z-index: 100; left: 50px;
                            position: relative; top: 0px; display: none;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
                                    <br />
                                    <font color="gray" style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Level 3 QMS Forms</b></font>
                                </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the FORM tag the error message is telling you about?

Comment: i'm really an idiot!!!i don't have a Form tag in it!!!!i've added it in but stil i'm having problems..help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're posting back only to make the tables visible or not then please view this updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yjw3K/

Changes:

- `Visibility="false"` - inside style tag: `display:none;`
- Added code to show/hide tables on index.

If you still need to execute client code I would suggest looking into `onClientClick` which will execute client code and code behind code registered to the control.

**EDIT for clarity **

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var contentPlaceHolder = '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.images').click(function() {
        $('a.images').not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.4 }, 300);
        // Make this opaque
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);

        //hide all tables   
        $('[id*=tblLevel]').hide();
        //show indexed tabled
        $(contentPlaceHolder + 'tblLevel' + ($(this).index() + 1)).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much, that is exactly what i want. the problem now is when i tried it on me side, the fading is not working, no table shown. what is wrong here?am i missing any references or anything? **i've posted the exact code above, can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the code??** thank u!!

Comment: I've added a `$(document).ready(function(){ //your scripts });` and it works quite well. Please see my edit.

Comment: thank you!!!that line did it and is working!!!but i have anther problem now, it does not seems to work if i have a Masterpage.master. when i replaced the html,head and form tag with asp:Content, the fading works but it is not showing my tables.i've edited the code above, please help!!

Comment: okay, the reason it isnt working is because all the `runat="server"` elements are getting an id prefix of your content placeholder. if you run your project and in your browser right click and 'view source' go to the element and note down the ID. Post it here if you wish and ill assist you in editing your code. Solution 2: remove the runat=server tags from your table. Ciao! ;)

Comment: i don't know if this is the ID u're talking about but i've edited my post above.Please let me know if this is the right code u're looking for!!thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Please see my edit above - essentially we're just concatenating the content place holder id to your elements.